# How to display the errors before php-cs-fixer corrects them in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor, php-cs-fixer

I try to use php-cs-fixer within Atom. It works fine but I would like to see the errors before the corrections. Like this picture seen in the documentation (see at the bottom of the screen):

[image]

How to do that?